# Wrapping Conditional inside ISNULL Conditional | mySQL

Tags: mysql

**Currently I have the following conditional inside my SELECT statement:**

```
  IF ((`date1` IS NOT NULL AND `date1` <> 0), DATE_FORMAT(`date1`, "%M %D %Y"), 
  DATE_FORMAT(`date2`, "%M %D %Y")) AS finaldate
```

But under certain conditions instead of presenting a date for `finaldate` the outcome of the conditional is `NULL`. Is it possible to wrap this conditional inside a `ISNULL` conditional?

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result. The question is not clear enough to answer it as is.

Comment: What I mean is in the query results, `finaldate` will come out to be `NULL`. Instead of showing a `NULL` value I need a blank value to be presented instead ex: `""` instead of `NULL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to convert a `NULL` to another value you can use `COALESCE()`. For example:

```
COALESCE(<my_expression>, ' ')
```

In this case, if the value of `<my_expression>` is null, it will be rendered as a space.

In your case this could become something like:

```
COALESCE(
  IF ((`date1` IS NOT NULL AND `date1` <> 0), DATE_FORMAT(`date1`, "%M %D %Y"), 
  DATE_FORMAT(`date2`, "%M %D %Y"),
  ' '
) AS finaldate
```

Comment: Thank you for your help